# Enumerate all n-tuples in parallel

Tags: algorithms, combinatorics, parallel-computing, enumeration

Let $T = \{0, 1\} ^ {n}$, i.e. set of all $n$-bit binary strings ($n$-tuples). Let $f : T \to T$ be a function, that maps one string to another. $f$ is bijective, but $f^{-1}$ is hard to compute.

It is obviously known, that $f^{k}(t) = t$ for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$, and some $t \in T$, i.e. $f$ has at least one cycle. Number of such cycles along with their lengths is unknown.

The task is to visit all elements in $T$ in parallel to speed up enumerating for large values of $n$. The challenge is to split tuples into batches.

Let's suppose, that there are several cycles with relatively high probability. And these cycles have different length: a few are of length of order $O(|T|/c)$ for $c \sim 10$, other ones are of length $l \in \mathbb{N}$ for $l \ll |T|$. Is there a better way to select initial elements for thread workers, than just picking several distinct random elements?

Suppose $n$ to be large enough to disallow memoizing all visited strings, e.g. $n = 128$. Is there a tricky way to detect if two threads actually iterate over the same cycle?

The initial task is to find such cycles for some $f$ and some element on each of them. Maybe there is a better way to solve the problem, than enumerating all possible elements.